# Cli_cppuhelper DLL - BadImageFormatException

Tags: model-view-controller, dll, command-line-interface

I’m trying to create open office calc with asp net and I always get this error when I start debugging.

“Couldn’t load assembly ‘cli_cppuhelper’ or it’s dependencies. “

Yes, I know it could be related to x86 and x64 cause the project is x64. That being said, I created a console project to test it and I get another error.

“Could not load file or assembly ‘cli_cppuhelper’.a dynamic link library initialization routine failed”

I had some problems before but I was able do solve (couldn’t find cli dlls in GAC. I had to reinstall open office and the SDK).

I’m using cli_basetypes, cli_cppuhelper, cli_oootypes, cli_ure and cli_ureteres from open office sdk>sdk>Cli and I have all 5 dlls registered in GAC.

I Tried installing open office and open office sdk so I have all dlls available. Their version is 4.1.9 x86.